# Как Подсчитывать Количество комментариев к статье и вывести этот подсчет в блок

Tags: php, sql

[image: это таблица comments[![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mUs1.png)у меня есть categorie.php, в котором хранятся статьи из выбранной категории, в каждом блоке  со статьей есть блок, в котором должно выводиться количество комментариев к статье. В questionshow.php выводится статья. У меня вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы посчитать количество комментариев на странице questionshow.php и вывести результат подсчета в блок на странице categorie.php?
Пишите если чего то вам не хватает, чтобы понять мой вопрос, скину вам все необходимое.

```
<?php 
$article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `categorie_id` = " . (int) $_GET['id'] ); 

if( mysqli_num_rows($article) <= 0 ) 
{
?> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row"> 
<section class="content__left col-md-8"> 
<div class="block"> 
<h3>Ошибка!</h3> 
<div class="block__content"> 
<div class="full-text"> 
Запрашиваемая Вами Страница Не Существует! 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 

</section> 
<section class="content__right col-md-4"> 
<div class="block"> 
<h3></h3> 
<div class="block__content"> 

</div> 
</div> 
</section> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<?php 
} else 

$art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($article); 
?>



<?php
$categories = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles_categories`");
while( $cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories) )
?>                          

<?php 
$art_cat = false; 
foreach( $categories as $cat ) 
{ 
if( $cat['id'] == $art['categorie_id']) 
{ 
$art_cat = $cat; 
break; 
} 
} 
?> 


<div class="w-100 mt-4">  
<div class="block block-shadow p-1">
<div class="block block-shadow light-input-bg py-1"> 

<h3 class="light-text m-0 d-inline-block"><?php echo $art_cat['title']; ?></h3>


<p class="light-text d-inline-block m-0 mt-1 float-right"><?php echo 'Вопросов: ' . mysqli_num_rows($article);?></p>
</div>
<div class="p-2">
<div class="card example-2 square scrollbar-dusty-grass-2 square thin bg-transparent">


<?php 
echo'<a href=/questionshow.php?id='. $art['id']. '><div class="question-block block-shadow mt-1 mb-0">
<div><h3>'. mb_substr(strip_tags($art['title']) , 0, 75, 'utf-8'). '</h3></div>
<div class="question-block-right">
<div class="question-block-right-in text-white">
<span class="time-question">'.$art['pubdate'].'</span>
</div>
<p>Ответов <span>'.mysqli_num_rows($article).'</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</a>';
?>
Комментарии хранятся в questionshow.php.Вот код комментариев:

<?php 
$comments = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `id_articles` = " . (int) $art['id'] . " ORDER BY `id` DESC ");
?>
                        <h5 class="mt-2 light-text mb-0">Комментарии</h5>
                         <?php
                                {
while( $comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments) ) 
{ 
                        echo'<div style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;" class="block block-shadow light-bg p-0">
                            <div class="block block-shadow light-bg m-0 py-1">
                                <h3 class="light-text m-0 d-inline-block">
                                    <img class="d-inline-block" style="border-radius: 90px;" width="35" src=/images/avatars/200x200.png alt="">
                                    <p style="font-size: 20px" class="d-inline-block m-0">'.$comment ['author'].'</p>
                                </h3>
                                <p style="padding: 10px 0px;" class="light-text d-inline-block m-0 mt-0 float-right">'.$comment ['pubdate'].'</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="block block-shadow dark-bg m-1 light-text">
                                <p class="mb-0">' .$comment['text']. '</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
                                  }
                   ?>

                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
```

[image: это comments]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вызывает затруднение? не можете составить запрос?

Comment: А как мы скажем как считать комментарии, если вы не приводите структуру БД и где вообще хранятся эти самые комментарии. И делать это конечно надо в том же запросе, который получает статьи, выполнить left join таблицы статей с таблицей комментариев, сделать group by до статьи с count(комментарий.id) даст кол-во коментариев

Comment: @Mike добавил код с выводом комментариев, как вам структуру бд скинуть?

Comment: @n.osennij затруднение в том, что комментарии в questionshow.php находятся, а там где нужно вывести результат подсчета находится в файле category.php, тоесть в разных страницах, файлах и как запросы делать мне с разных страниц я не понимаю : (

Comment: Что значит находятся? Комментарии находятся в базе данных.

Comment: Коментарии в БД находятся. в php "находится" они не могут. Еще раз повторяю, количество надо считать на уровне sql. запрос вида `select a.x, a.y, a.z, ..., count(c.id) comm_cnt from articles a left join comments c on c.id_articles = a.id group by a.x, a.y, a.z` отлично даст вам прямо из БД список с статей  с количеством комментариев и ничего на стороне php считать вообще не понадобится. Все что надо, это потратить день на изучение SQL, что бы писать подобные запросы самому.

Comment: @n.osennij так комментарии находятся в таблице comments, а статьи в другой, ничего это не меняет

Comment: из-за того, что вы называете вещи не своими именами, вы себя же и путаете. Ещё раз. Комментарии хранятся у вас в базе данных. А со стороны php вы можете получить с помощью запроса информацию о них. В любом файле. Где угодно. Просто написав код запроса на получение этих данных из базы.

Comment: @Mike что означают a.x a.y a.z    c.id comm_cnt from articles, я прикреплю фотографию структур двух нужных таблиц, а то я мало информации дал, чтобы вы адекватно обьяснили, все я добавил структуру

Comment: a.x, a.y, a.z это просто поля таблицы articles которые вам действительно нужны в выборке. А c.id это поле id из таблицы comments там же есть свой id ? И по вашей структуре просто менять их на ваши названия полей я все равно не буду. Путь как оно примерно делается я показал. А точно под вашу структуру никто за вас править запрос не будет

Comment: @Mike я добавил структуру двух таблиц, они подходят под ваш запрос?

Comment: Подходит конечно. На будущее, структуры можно давать текстом в виде create table. Это особенно полезно когда вопрос касается  sql. И все таки попробуйте потратить немного времени на изучение sql. на том уровне на котором сделан этот запрос изучение должно занять несколько часов

Comment: Уважаемый автор. Вам необходимо срочно(!) ознакомится с главными SOLID принципами. Я настоятельно рекомендую сделать это незамедлительно, в ином случае, через определенное время Вы не сможете разобрать свой собственный код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `categorie_id` = " . (int) $_GET['id']

$_GET['id'] => не делайте так ни когда sql инъекция.

$id = inval($_GET['id']);

SELECT count() FROM `articles` WHERE `categorie_id` = $id
// если подсчитать только один 

SELECT categorie_id, COUNT(*) FROM `articles` WHERE `categorie_id` = $id GROUP BY categorie_id
// если подсчет всех, чего !НЕ рекомендую 

// нужно передать массив id
$id = 1,2..;
SELECT categorie_id, COUNT(*) FROM `articles` WHERE `categorie_id` IN $id GROUP BY categorie_id
// некоторое кол-во
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function inval()  вот такую ошибку выдает, я всего лишь удалил вот этот запрос    SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `categorie_id` = " . (int) $_GET['id'] и заменил его на ваш $id = inval($_GET['id']);


$article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT count() FROM `articles` WHERE `categorie_id` = $id");        В чем проблема и почему через $_GET небезопасно передавать id?

Comment: Видимо у меня на версии php 5.5 функция inval не работает

Comment: Отпечатка intval() => https://php.ru/manual/function.intval.html

Comment: теперь работает, спасибо, получайте галку